# Change max-width using Jquery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> HTML working with class="line1"

```
            <div class="line line1 row" onscroll="myFunction()">
                <div class="tag bold flex tagline col-sm-2">
                    HTML / CSS
                </div>
                <div class="tag-percent col-sm-1 ml-auto"><span>95%</span></div>
            </div>
```

> CSS  max-width: 10%; at pseudo:after element

```
   .line1:after{
    max-width: 10%
     }
```

> Script to set max-width to 85%

```
<script>
    function myFunction(){
        const element = document.querySelector('.line1:after');
        element.style.maxWidth = "85%";
        console.log(element);
            }

  </script>
```

I tried using using getComputedStyle.getPropertyValue but it is read-only.
Can anyone solve it using jQuery or JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

you can't select the pseudo element. so u can add one more class call `line1-after`

in css put

```
.line1-after:after{
 max-width: 85%
}
```

add this class

```
$('.line1').addClass("line1-after");
```

Comment: Yeah. that didn't work. max-width: 85% is applied to div but .line:after {max-width : 95%} remains same.

Comment: it is pseudo element. u can't manipulate it . So u will put this class  under the line class to apply to div.